# How to retrieve user's consented version from ad b2c?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am using AZure Ad B2C tenant and  i have custom Consent field on signup. This is working fine and whenever we update consent its prompting to user.

I have to keep history of user's consent. Lets say on signup user1 accepted Consent (v1) and some time later user1 accepted Consent (v2), etc.

I need the history of all consents accepted/declined by user. Is that possible to retrieve?

I have tried the following.

1. Added two extension claim along with consent field with string type (since stringcollection is not supported for extension claims)

   ```
   <ClaimType Id="extension_TermsOfUseConsented">
       <DisplayName>Terms of Use Consented</DisplayName>
       <DataType>string</DataType>
       <UserInputType>CheckboxMultiSelect</UserInputType>
       <Restriction>
         <Enumeration Text="I am agreeing to the terms of use" Value="2018-10-29" SelectByDefault="false" />
       </Restriction>
     </ClaimType>      
   <ClaimType Id="extension_TempConsent">
     <DisplayName>temp Consent</DisplayName>
     <DataType>string</DataType>      
   </ClaimType>

   <ClaimType Id="extension_ConsentHistory">
     <DisplayName>consent history</DisplayName>
     <DataType>string</DataType>      
   </ClaimType>
   ```
2. Added the above field in signup relyingparty section.

   ```
   <RelyingParty>
   <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn-withConsent" />
   <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
     <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
     <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
     <InputClaims>          
     </InputClaims>
     <OutputClaims>
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TermsOfUseConsented" />
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_ConsentHistory" />
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TempConsent" />

     </OutputClaims>
     <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
   </TechnicalProfile>
   ```
3. In user journey step 3, reading the above claim in "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" technical profile.

   ```
          <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
          <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
           <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
           </Metadata>
           <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
           <InputClaims>
           <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
           </InputClaims>
           <OutputClaims>

           <!-- Optional claims -->
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TermsOfUseConsented" /> 
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TempConsent" />
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_ConsentHistory" />
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_ReadStringFromVP" />
         </OutputClaims>
         <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
       </TechnicalProfile>
   ```
4. In step 4, reading consent value and if terms is new then prompting user to accept. In claims exchange calling below technical profile.

   ```
      <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-Consent">
         <DisplayName>User Consent</DisplayName>
         <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
         <Metadata>
           <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.consent</Item>
         </Metadata>
         <CryptographicKeys>
           <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
         </CryptographicKeys>
         <InputClaims />
         <OutputClaims>
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TermsOfUseConsented" Required="true" />
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TempConsent" DefaultValue="," />
           <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_ConsentHistory" DefaultValue="," />
         </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>                
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AppendConsent" />        
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="TakeConsentBackup" />             
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
         <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
           <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-WriteUserConsentByObjectId-ThrowIfNotExists" />
         </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
       </TechnicalProfile>
   ```
5. In ClaimsTransformation doing some string manupulation

   ```
     <ClaimsTransformation Id="TakeConsentBackup" TransformationMethod="FormatStringMultipleClaims">
       <InputClaims>
       <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_ConsentHistory" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
       <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TempConsent" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
     </InputClaims>
     <InputParameters>
       <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{1},{0}" />
     </InputParameters>
     <OutputClaims>
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_ConsentHistory" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
     </OutputClaims>
   </ClaimsTransformation>

    <ClaimsTransformation Id="AppendConsent" TransformationMethod="FormatStringMultipleClaims">
       <InputClaims>
       <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TermsOfUseConsented" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
       <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TempConsent" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
     </InputClaims>
     <InputParameters>
       <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{1}{0}" />
     </InputParameters>
     <OutputClaims>
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TempConsent" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
     </OutputClaims>
   </ClaimsTransformation>
   ```
6. In AAD-WriteUserConsentByObjectId-ThrowIfNotExists writing the extension claim as below.

   ```
   <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-WriteUserConsentByObjectId-ThrowIfNotExists">
   <Metadata>
   <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
   <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
   </Metadata>
   <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
   <InputClaims>
   <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
   </InputClaims>
   <PersistedClaims>
   <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
   <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_TermsOfUseConsented" />         
   <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_ConsentHistory" />
   ```
7. On claim return, its showing string manipulated values (on time on consent)
   but on next login (without consent) its not returning the extension field. getting only extension_TermsOfUseConsented field value. 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOfBY.png)
8. The expected claim extension manipulated in policy only not from user input. Is that a problem?

what i am missing here?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Muthukumar. Can you send the consent data to [a REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw)?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPadgett. This is good. Is there any way to view the history in Azure AD B2C tenant?